# SSL error on postman request to Amazon ECS container

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, postman, amazon-ecs

To give a little context before the problem:
I'm using a ECS Cluster based on a T2.micro Ec2 machine to run two containers, a Keycloak server and a nodeJS api to menage the Keycloak Server.
The keycloak server is working fine, however when I try to make a POST request using POSTMAN I get this error:

> Error: write EPROTO 1046529048:error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER:../../third_party/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:242:

The *Inbound* rules:
[image: Inbound]

The *Outbound* rules:
[image: outbound]

Comment: Did you setup ssl and https on the instance?

Comment: @Marcin Yes, sure. I remembered to open the 443 port after the post. I'll update it.